# What is the difference between PRANAYAMA and vipassana meditation?

Tags: yoga, meditation

What is the difference between  PRANAYAMA and vipassana Meditation ?

I know that the founder of vipassana Meditation is  S.N. Goenka and Pranayam by Baba Ramdev

Comment: Ummm, might I suggest a correction to you, if you will?,.... Baba Ramadev is a promoter of the Pranayama and other Yogic techniques, **not the "founder"**. Pranayam is a part of the Ashtanga Yoga, and has been so eternally, as per scriptures.